# How to calculate similarities between test and train documents

Tags: vector, text-classification, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to calculate similarities between test and train documents and label them. Here is the code but it doesn't work. I'd also appreciate if somebody could explain the idea.

```
def calculate_similarities(self, vecTestDoc, vectorsOfTrainDocs):
    list_of_similarities = []
    for vector in vectorsOfTrainDocs:
        label = vectorsOfTrainDocs.key()
        list_of_similarities += [(self.calculate_similarities(vector, vecTestDoc), label)]
    return list_of_similarities
```

Here's the error:

```
File "..\classification.py", line 98, in calculate_similarities
label = vectorsOfTrainDocs.key()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Edit: I've defined two more functions and have been working on a different solution. Here are they:

```
def cosine_similarity(self, weightedA, weightedB):
    dotAB = dot(weightedA, weightedB)
    normA = math.sqrt(dot(weightedA, weightedA))
    normB = math.sqrt(dot(weightedB, weightedB))
    return dotAB / (normA * normB)

def fit(self, doc_collection):
    self.doc_collection = doc_collection
    self.vectorsOfDoc_collection = [(doc, self.doc_collection.tfidf(doc.token_counts))
                                    for doc in self.doc_collection.docid_to_doc.values()]
```

I believe something like this would work but there are still error messages... What should I change?

```
return [self.doc_collection.cosine_similarity(vecTestDoc) in vectorsOfTrainDocs]
```

Comment: Your vectorsOfTrainDocs is a list of vectors and probably doesn't contain any labels. You could check the raw vector value.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the code, maybe it's better now...